# Azure DevOps Release Sending email

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline set up dev qa and prod. QA and PROD triggers are set to after stage with pre-deployment approvals set up

Problem I facing I have feature which I broken into 3 sprints ( user stories ) after each sprint all dev work is deploy to dev for testing. After dev is deployed the email going out to pre-deployment approvals for QA which is not what I need

Solution I looking for is each sprints get deployed to dev. When I am done with the whole feature I can add a message and click a button or something then the email must go out to the pre-deployment approvals can this be done using triggers are set to after stage?

Comment: Hi @smarteez, please check my answer below to set a post-deployment approvals. If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a post-deployment approvals for dev stage, after deployment for dev stage is finished, it need approval before the release is triggered to other stages. After you approve the post-deployment approvals for dev stage, the email for pre-deployment approvals will send.

[image]